# how to get UIView 's angle after CGAffineTransform?

Tags: angle

i have been do more  CGAffineTransform.

how to get current Uiview's  angle?

i want to do something when angle==[M_PI/2 ~ M_PI]?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`CGFloat radians = atan2f(self.view.transform.b, self.view.transform.a);
CGFloat degrees = radians * (180 / M_PI);`

Answer (score -1):

You can check .transfrom property of UIView for that.